# Asociar nombre por id php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, bucles, relaciones

Saludos tengo este codigo para un loop en una tabla, funciona perfectamente pero lo unico que no comprendo como hacer es asociar el rel_id del **row2** con el nombre de dicho id en la **row3**

La tabla **tbltaks (sql2 en el codigo)** tiene una columna llamada **rel_id** que se relaciona con la columna **id** de la tabla **tblprojects (sql3 en el codigo)** que tambien tiene una columna con el nombre que deseo mostrar.

Como hago para asociar el **rel_id** con el **id** y mostrar el **nombre** dentro de este loop?

```
<?php 
echo '<table id="tabla2" class="table table-striped">';
$mysql_id = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass');
mysql_select_db('database', $mysql_id);
$sql="SELECT * FROM tasks";
$sql2="SELECT * FROM tbltasks";
$sql3="SELECT * FROM tblprojects";
$resultado = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error());
$resultado2 = mysql_query($sql2) or die( mysql_error());
$resultado3 = mysql_query($sql3) or die( mysql_error());

while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado)) {
       $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado2);
       $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultado3);

echo   '<tr><td>' .$row['name']. '</td>';
echo   '<td>' .$row['actualStart']. '</td>';
echo   '<td>' .$row['actualEnd']. '</td>';
echo   '<td>' .$row2['rel_id']. '</td>';
echo   '<td>' .$row2['status']. '</td></tr>';

}
echo  '</table>';
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, puedo ver que estas usando 3 consulta y tienes tres tablas estas no están relacionadas entre si o son todas tablas sueltas. Si están relacionadas solo u ne las con **join**. Gracias

Comment: Hola @YoelRodriguez las tablas tbltasks y tblprojects se relacionan con **rel_id** dentro de **tbltasks** que es el **id** en **tblprojects**

Comment: En este caso en lugar de esas dos consultas usa una sola unida por **join** ahora la primera se la primera tabla se relaciona con alguna de las otras dos también la unes y asi puedes obtener los datos que deseas

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo puedes solucionar con una consulta con **`INNER JOIN`** y asi puedes ahorrarte hacer incluso las 3 consultas, al menos si quieres hacer la relacion de ***tbltasks*** y ***tblprojects*** la consulta podria quedar las siguientes maneras (Dependiendo de la informacion que solicites):

> **SELECT * FROM** tbltasks **INNER JOIN** tblprojects **ON** tbltasks.rel_id = tblprojects.id;

Si nada mas utilizaras el nombre de ***tblprojects*** puedes usar:

> **SELECT** tbltasks.*, nombre.tblprojects **FROM** tbltasks **INNER JOIN** tblprojects **ON** tbltasks.rel_id = tblprojects.id;

Espero te ayude a solucionar tu problema, Saludos!